# Xcode Auto layout not working on all devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have setup auto layout constraints to have an image position properly on (lower end of the screen) multiple devices. Please see the settings here -

[image]

but I think the top section of the settings is messing up the image in few devices -

[image]

How can I force the x,y, height and width to be responsive on different screens and just follow the constraints mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide more complete layout information (including adjacent views) it is best.

From the layout information you provided, the constraints are incorrect.

1.`Trailling` and `Leading` can determine the `horizontal` latitude of the view, `Center X` is repeated

2. `Bottom` and `Align Bottom` are duplicates, retaining one
3. `Vertical` latitude determination also requires a `Top` constraint
4. After setting the constraints, don't set the `x`, `y` shown in your screenshot, it will upset your existing constraints, there will be a yellow prompt for you to update the constraints.

Each view only needs horizontal and vertical constraints, the extra constraints will not be effective, and a warning will be prompted.

For `UILabel`, `UIImageView`, you don't need to set the width and height, depending on the content, there will be a default width and height.